# Finding the steady states of a quadratic ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quadratics, steady-state

How would I go about finding the steady states

I know I need to set $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ but then I'm struggling with the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$ \beta+x\alpha(1-\frac{x}{\kappa})-x(\mu+\nu+\delta) =0$$
and then
$$ \alpha x^2+\kappa(-\alpha+\mu+\nu+\delta)x-\beta\kappa=0.$$
You can use quadratic formula to the equilibrium points.